# including table of contents on all slides

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am making a presentation in Latex beamer. My presentation includes a table of contents. I would like the table of contents to be visible as a left-handed sidebar throughout the presentation. Preferentially I would like the current section to be highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

`\useoutertheme{sidebar}` -- or one of the themes based on it, see https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/ for an overview